# New Android Developer Studio project "peer not authenticated" issues

Tags: android

I'm absolutely brand new to android development, and my last serious programming is about 10 years old (and using VB.net).  Trying to get into this now.

I'm running Android Developer Studio 2.1.2 on Windows 10.  JRE and JDK versions are jdk1.8.0_101.  Launched a brand new project, which is phone and tablet app, and selected default options for API version.

I immediately get the following error:`Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not download support-v4.aar (com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1)
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.1.1/support-v4-24.1.1.aar'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/24.1.1/support-v4-24.1.1.aar'.
>   peer not authenticated`

I've seen where this is possibly a certificate trust issue.  I dowloaded the cer files for jcenter.bintray.com, and tried using keytool -import command, and got an access denied error.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

add this code in build.gradle

```
repositories {
mavenLocal()
maven {
    name "jcenter"
    url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'd seen (and added) that previously, to no effect.

Turned out the answer was that I had started a project using an API version that I hadn't already downloaded the SDK for.  I think when I first installed, I'd grabbed the SDK for API 23, and the sample "getting started" texts I was using referenced something lower.  After I downloaded all the SDKs for the different APIs, the issue went away.